# How to make nexus 10 as a monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, performance-monitor, nexus-7

I have an old nexus 10. It is slow, but fully functional. I have an old notebook which the monitor does not work. The nexus has a mini HDMI connector. Is it possible to make the nexus 10 as a monitor of my notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting the Nexus to the Laptop directly might not work. 
See this website for more information: [Nexus 7 Display for Raspberry](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=158525).

If you really want to connect your phone to the Laptop, you could try things like TeamViewer. It runs pretty smooth on a phone an the controls are ok-ish!

Therefore you have to connect the Laptop to a screen once and set up teamviewer.

Good luck!

Comment: Better alternative to teamviewer is VNC. It has less features but in return is much faster. Plus I'm not sure if TV works on LAN only (it might though), I mean, it would work but if it goes through WAN the speed would decrease again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most convenient way is to use [Spacedesk](https://new.spacedesk.ph/) App.
(Windows/Android).

*(it is necessary that the version of Android allows to launch App client part)*.

In the end, you'll get a full External Display for Windows PC (via wi-fi).